# "strongly relational m-consistency when the domains contain at most m elements implies satisfiability" plain wrong?

Tags: satisfiability, constraint-satisfaction

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_consistency#Relational_consistency_and_satisfiability) states

> A constraint satisfaction problem may be relationally consistent, have
>   no empty domain or unsatisfiable constraint, and yet be unsatisfiable.
>   There are however some cases in which this is not possible.
>
> The first case is that of strongly relational
>   m-consistent problem when the domains contain at most m elements.

This would imply that any problem with domains of size m that is stongly m-consistent, is satisfiable. However on the same page they mention 3-colorability. It is NP-complete and consists of binary constraints on variables with domain size 3. Generally it should be possible to achieve strong-3-consistency in about $O(n^3)$, so the above statement should be wrong as it implies P=NP. What did they mean to say when the wrote the above statement? Or am I interpreting it in a wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the quoted statement is correct.  Wikipedia gives a proof in the next four sentences that immediately follow the quote you gave.

The constraints that arise from 3-colorability are not strongly relational 3-consistent, so the quoted statement implies nothing about 3-colorability.  Consequently, there is no contradiction.

(Why aren't the constraints from 3-colorability strongly relational 3-consistent?  Consider a star graph, with a vertex $v$ that is connected to three other vertices $w,x,y$.  There is one constraint per edge in the graph: e.g., one constraint that constrains the colors assigned to vertices $v,w$; one for $v,x$; and one for $v,y$.  Suppose we have a partial assignment that assigns $w$ the color red, $x$ blue, and $y$ green.  Then there is no way to assign a color to $v$ that makes the three constraints for $vw$, $vx$, and $vy$ all valid.  Thus, the constraints do not satisfy the definition of strongly relational 3-consistency.)

Comment: I see now. Many times strongly relational i-consistency cannot be achieved with only binary constraints.